# Помогите пожалуйста с ошибкой Django NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django

Сама ошибка

```
NoReverseMatch at /mycart/order/
Reverse for 'product_page' with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<page_number>[0-9]+)/(?P<img_number>[0-9]+)/$', '(?P<page_number>[0-9]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/mycart/order/
Django Version: 2.2.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'product_page' with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<page_number>[0-9]+)/(?P<img_number>[0-9]+)/$', '(?P<page_number>[0-9]+)/$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 668
Python Executable:  C:\Users\пк\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\пк\\Desktop\\py\\Django\\shop\\shop',
 'C:\\Users\\пк\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\пк\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\пк\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\пк\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
 'C:\\Users\\пк\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\пк\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pyinstaller-3.5.dev0+d5a902d9e-py3.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\пк\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pywin32_ctypes-0.2.0-py3.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\пк\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\altgraph-0.16.1-py3.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\пк\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\macholib-1.11-py3.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\пк\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pefile-2018.8.8-py3.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\пк\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\future-0.17.1-py3.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\пк\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\пк\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\пк\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Ср, 10 Июл 2019 00:14:19 +0300
```

Шаблон страницы с ошибкой

```
{% extends "maket.html" %}

{% block page_name %}
    {{ page_name }}
{% endblock %}


{% block shop_name %}
    {{shop_name}}
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    <center>
    <table cellpadding=20 border=5 width=80%>

        {% if fr is "cart" %}
            {% for product in products %}
            <tr>
                <td width=100><img src={{product.img_src.url}} width=100></img></td>
                <td width=100><a href='{% url "product_page" product.id %}'>{{product.name}}</a></td>
                <td>{{product.mini_descr}}</td>
                <td width=70>{{product.coast}} руб.</td>

            </tr>
            {% endfor %}

        {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td width=100><img src={{products.img_src.url}} width=100></img></td>
                <td width=100><a href='{% url "product_page" products.id %}'>{{products.name}}</a></td>
                <td>{{products.mini_descr}}</td>
                <td width=70>{{products.coast}} руб.</td>


            </tr>
        {% endif %}



    </table>




    {% for f in form %}

        <p>{{f}}</p><br>

    {% endfor %}

    </center>
{% endblock %}
```

И кусок из views.py

```
class make_order(View):

    def get(self, request, product_id=None):

        username = auth.get_user(request).username

        if username:
            user = auth.get_user(request)
            fr = ""

            if product_id:
                fr = "prod"
                products = product.objects.get(id=product_id)
            else:
                fr = "cart"
                products = Cart.view(user=user).all()

                print(products)

            return render(request, "market/order_page.html", context={
                                "shop_name": shop_name,
                                "page_name": "Заказ",
                                "user": user,
                                "products": products, 
                                "from": fr   
                })

        return redirect("login_page")
```

urls.py

```
from .views import *
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path("?<str:cat>", category_view.as_view(), name="category_view"),
    path('', index, name="index_page"),

    path('<int:page_number>/', product_page.as_view(), name="product_page"),
    path('<int:page_number>/<int:img_number>/', product_page.as_view(), name="product_page"),

    path('registration/', registration_user.as_view(), name='register_page'),
    path('login/', login_user.as_view(), name="login_page"),

    path('mycart/', mycart_view.as_view(), name="users_cart"),
    path("mycart/exclude_product/<int:p_id>", exclude_product.as_view(),
                                            name="exclude_product"),
    path("mycart/add_product/<int:p_id>", add_product.as_view(), name="add_product"),
    path("mycart/clean", cart_clean.as_view(), name="cart_clean"),

    path("mycart/order/", make_order.as_view(), name="do_order"),
    path("mycart/order/<int:product_id>", make_order.as_view(), name="do_order")

]
```

модель Cart

```
class Cart(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(product)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Корзина"
        verbose_name_plural="Корзины"

    def __str__(self):
        return "Корзина пользователя {}".format(self.user.username)

    def view(user):
        cart = Cart.objects.get(user=user)
        return cart.products

    def clean(self):
        self.products.clear()
```

Если нужно что-то еще то пишите

Comment: Что у вас в `urls.py`?

Comment: @Andrey добавил

Comment: попробуйте `{% url .... page_number=product.id %}` а еще после `else` у вас опечатка (должно быть `product`, полагаю)

Comment: @ZaArs Не получается, а после else вроде правильно, если else то туда попадает объект, а не список, просто имя оставил для удобства, и меньшего количества кода. И кстати, один момент не сказал, после else все работает, когда только 1 объект, а через цикл вот эта ошибка.

Comment: покажите, что за Cart

Comment: @ZaArs добавил модель cart

Comment: `Reverse for 'product_page' with arguments '('',)'` как видно передаются пустые аргументы, смотрите что возвращает ваш Cart.view.all

Comment: Добавьте и product

Comment: Cart.view.all это query-set :
<QuerySet [<product: Python>]>

Comment: Кстати, есть еще одна страница, там с cart написано тоже самое, но там все работает

Comment: @ЕлисейИонов у вас в `urls.py` два паттерна названы одним именем - `product_page`. Во время поиска django выберет последний. Это может и не решит вашу текущую проблему, но лучше дайте им разные имена.

Comment: @Andrey Я понимаю что так нельзя делать, но имена я одинаковые поставил потому-что это как бы одна и таже страница, но это самый простой способ переключать картинки, а так окей, больше так делать не буду.

Comment: Добавьте `^` в начале и `$` в конце регулярок product_page, тогда можно оставть с одинаковым именем. не обратил изначально внимания

Comment: @ZaArs У меня немного другая проблема...